# PHP Laravel after setting up laravel i run public/home

Tags: php, laravel

I set up laravel 5.0 when i call this url http://127.0.0.1/myProject/public/ it show me laravel logo. But when i call http://127.0.0.1/myProject/public/home
It show me 404 page not found error. I also made a new controller hello but it is also same error.

Comment: Try to call http://127.0.0.1/myProject/public/index.php/home

Comment: Also what web-server do you use?

Answer (score 2):

U can use virutal host 
Enter your path at documentRoot to public folder in project
and enter your virtual domain

DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/testni/public/"
    ServerName example.dev

U cant access your hello controller if it use auth midlleware without login

Answer (score 1):

The laravel setup comes with Login and Registration Module in itself. The best way in MVC projects is to setup Virtual Host on your machine (this is not compulsion).

The `http://127.0.0.1/myProject/public/home` should take you to `http://127.0.0.1/myProject/auth/login`. Where you will find a Login form (presented by fresh Laravel Installation).

The reason for your problem must be bugs in your installation. Please see the Laravel Documentation(Laracasts) more precisely.